# How to modify the childs text from a merge layout from the include xml tag?

Tags: android, xml, layout

I want to somehow modify the content of the merge layout from the include tag. Is that possible?

Layout picAndText.xml:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 

        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/golden_gate" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"

        android:padding="12dip"

        android:background="#AA000000"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"

        android:text="Golden Gate" />

</merge>
```

And the layout xml that uses picAndText.xml:

```
<include layout="@layout/picAndText" android:id="@+id/picText" />
```

Please note this is an example of what I would like to acomplish. I want to reuse complex layouts with multiple children but I need different text on them every time I reuse these without having to copy the whole layout everywhere...

Thanks!
-Jona

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do correctly, I don't think its possible from XML.  Instead, you can update the text when you load the layout in code.

Comment: Yeah, I read through the Android APIs and just didn't seem possible but I wanted to ask cause I thought maybe just maybe there is a way...